# Default Template on Android Studio deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio

Earlier I was asking about how to come over from Windows phone development.  I didn't just sit and wait for replies I got started.

I installed Android Studio.  I learned that it didn't have the 4.4 API by default (the version of Android my new phone will be running) so I located the SDK manager and installed the missing SDK.
 The preview pane for the layout editor could not render...I learnt I needed to go to the module settings and change the target there, then to the preview pane drop-down and change the targeted Android version there.
I added a simple button and then realised I have an error with the java ...that I have yet to touch!

```
public class MainDisplay extends ActionBarActivity {
```

> ActionBarActivity is deprecated.

...but that's the default template!

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
```

> cannot resolve symbol R.

...again, it's default "blank activity" template.

I checked for updates and it is the latest version of Android Studio: 1.2.1.1.  My JDK is the latest version: `jdk1.8.0_45 (64bit)`.

Any ideas why my Android Studio (freshly installed today) is generating broken templates or any other ideas about how to fix?

EDIT

I uninstalled Android Studio, the SDK and deleted all folders created by it
then I reinstalled it all. I installed version 1.7 of Java JDK.

I got the same errors on a new project.

This is the source code it generates:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

As you can see, it is extending the deprecated class, and adding those R's it can't resolve .....and this is before I have done anything.

But for tonight, I have run out of time. I had 7 hours free to start porting my app to Android and it's all gone setting up the dev environment.  I wouldn't mind but it's not working and I have no idea why.

Comment: This is a common issue with using the templates. Try to extend your `MainDisplay` from `AppCompatActivity` and resync your grade build files.

Comment: that fixed the deprecated part but still unable to resolve R

my first thought was that perhaps android studio is the old way of making android apps and there is some new way, but the build date in the about is this month.

im coming from visual studio and windows phone development in c# to android, should i be using some other program?

Comment: No, Android Studio id the official IDE from Google. Try to clean and rebuild the project, if this does not work, check your xml files for syntax errors.

Comment: not seeing any syntex errors but as i say its a fresh install...hmmm think ill uninstall it fully and the sdk and start again i must of messed something up in the installation

Comment: Did you try "invalidate Caches and restart"?

Comment: indeed
and clean/rebuild

and now re-installing. 

going to try downgrading java to 1.7 see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=49&v=5Be2mJzP-Uw) you should only make two changes

[image]

After I did this 2 changes all worked fine

For more information about this you have this [[1]](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) and this [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html)

**UPDATE 1**

After this change, clean your project and Sync Project with Gradle File.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

If after that you have problem **resolving symbol R errors after an SDK update in Android Studio** you can follow the steps showing in this [blog](http://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2014/11/fixing-android-studio-cannot-resolve.html)

Comment: still getting the cannot resolve R error 

thing is, this is the default starting template....there shouldn't need to be any changes to it until you start to code your app, it should just work

if you start up android studio go to new project and start one with the blank activity

then click into the MainActivity.java after a few seconds the errors are recognized by the IDE 
even tried minimum sdk as the latest (fixed the deprecated error but not the R one) which would be useless to develop for at the minute

Comment: David you can try this http://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2014/11/fixing-android-studio-cannot-resolve.html

Comment: David try this in Android Studio: "Tools" -> "Android" -> "Sync Project with Gradle Files"

Comment: that fixed it, thank you! but if i compile with the 5.0 sdk will that mean the app will not work on android 4.4 ?

Comment: @DavidEastwick The compileSdkVersion is the version of the API the app is compiled against. This means you can use Android API features included in that version of the API as well as all previous versions

Comment: In Manifest.xml you specified in android:minSdkVersion — The minimum version of the Android platform on which the application will run, specified by the platform's API Level identifier. For more info look here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

Comment: ah so as long as i dont use features of 5.0 then it will work on 4.4 (and so long as i have min sdk set to 4.4 or bellow) 

cool thank you

Comment: Jorge Casariego, can you just add to your answer the blog link that said about changing the sdk its compiled with so i can tag that as the answer please. also it was much appreciated!

Comment: @DavidEastwick now I edit how to resolve symbols R error in the answer

Answer (score 0):

First one. The ActionBarActivity is deprecated since API 21 (or 22 maybe) and now you should simply extend from Activity and use AppCompatDelegate. It's a really new feature so I suppose they haven't fixed it yet. I haven't tried using it yet so can't help with that. Even if the ActionBarActivity is deprecated it will work fine so it's not a problem for you.

Second. About the R being not found. The problem is inside your Gradle file (not the app one but the second one). In it you will need to fix a line under the dependencies tag (classpath) and change it to newer version. I can't seem to find the right version now but I have already solved this problem today for my friend so it will definitely work

It is also a bug in a current Android Studio version and after you fix it it will work fine.